# MySQL create memory leak in Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I have set a `JDBCRealm` for web-app inside tomcat, and when I reload it I got this from tomcat:
`SEVERE: A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.`

I use tomcat 6.0.24, with MySQL Connector 5.1.10,,,

Is there a way to clean it up, so tomcat won't display `SEVERE` message?

Comment: It isn't exactly a memory leak, it is a warning that Tomcat prevented one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a leak, or at least it is one that does not matter. If you have a singleton object (The JDBC driver) and it is never released until the app finishes, does it matter ?
The database will close any pending connections after a given amount of time.

If it really bothers you, you could fix it by overriding close method this way:

```
public class XBasicDataSource extends BasicDataSource {
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(DriverManager.getDriver(url));
        super.close();
    }
}
```

And use your XBasicDataSource .

Comment: @mabuzer Create a Jar file and put it in the lib folder for Tomcat. Use this as your DataSource